# How to handle validations between associated objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am having difficulty in validating two objects across some complex associations. Here's an example of what I have:

**car.rb**

```
class Car
  has_many :passengers
end
```

**passenger.rb**

```
class Passenger
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :info
end
```

Validations I need to do:

- The number of passengers is limited
- Passengers have an association to an object called `Info` that has "Employer" as a string. All passengers must have the same employer.

The interface has a multiselect box to choose passengers. Once you're done selecting the passengers, you click "Create" (or "Update", which has it's own set of problems).

When the controller tries to create the `Car`, it needs to run the car validations, then the passenger validations need to pass (employer check), and then the car needs to also ensure it's not exceeding the passenger count. If one of these fails, I need to reset and take them back to the new page.

During update, if it fails, I need to restore the original passengers to the car. I'm not sure how to perform the validations without actually saving the objects to the database though. In addition, once the objects are saved to the database, if the validations fail, then I don't know how to restore the previous passengers.

**How can I validate associated objects before saving them to the database?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use custom validation [custom_validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

```
 validate :validate_passengers

  def validate_passengers
    errors.add(:passengers, "too much") if tags.size > 5 #your limit
  end
```

This will validate the limit of passengers to car

Comment: This worked for me. I was able to use a custom validation, but I also ended up using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` along with the `allow_destroy` option.